# MySQL COUNT query in join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

The first table is the member table

```
MEMBER TABLE
ID    |  NAME
1     |  User
2     |  Another User
3     |  Some other User
```

and the second table is friends

```
FRIENDS TABLE
ID    |  member_id    |  Friend Name    |  Notified
1     |  1            |  Friend #1      |  0
2     |  1            |  Friend #1      |  1
3     |  2            |  Friend #1      |  0
4     |  1            |  Friend #1      |  1
5     |  2            |  Friend #1      |  1
```

What I like to do is to get the member table information but also to get the total notified friends for each member.

What I have done until now is that

```
SELECT
    M.ID
    M.NAME
    COUNT(F.notified)
FROM
    MEMBER AS M
LEFT JOIN
    FRIENDS AS F
ON
    F.member_id = M.id
WHERE
    F.notified = 1
GROUP BY
    M.id
```

But this, not working for me, because if I have a member with not notified friends, the query does not included in the results.

In the above code for example the member with ID 3 will not included in my results.

Any idea on how to modify that query in order to return even members with no notified friends ?

Kind regards
Merianos Nikos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a subquery in this way :

```
SELECT
    M.ID,
    M.NAME,
    (SELECT  COUNT(F.notified) FROM FRIENDS AS F WHERE F.member_id = M.id AND F.notified = 1) AS NUMFRIENDS
FROM
    MEMBER AS M 
GROUP BY
    M.id
```

Comment: Nice. But you don't even need the `GROUP BY M.id` with this approach.

Comment: This will run a seperate subquery for every record in the members table, which will probably start to impact performance quite quickly as the members table grows. Ypercube's answer is the better way to do this, because it won't have those issues.

Answer (score 5):

The `WHERE F.notified = 1` condition cancels the `LEFT` join, making it work as an `INNER` join. Move the condition to the joining `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    M.ID
    M.NAME
    COUNT(F.member_id)
FROM
      MEMBER AS M
  LEFT JOIN
      FRIENDS AS F
    ON
      F.member_id = M.id
    AND
      F.notified = 1
GROUP BY
    M.id ;
```